# na-adjectives in different tenses. これは真面目だった人です。

Tags: copula, na-adjectives

I need some help with basic grammar.
What is the difference between these sentences:

> 1. これは真面目だった人です。
> 2. これは真面目な人でした。
> 3. これは真面目だった人でした。

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This may look an aside, but referring to a person as これ is very rude in Japanese. You should at least use この人.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm only learning myself so I'm not sure, but I think all sentences are correct, since "真面目な/真面目だった" are both the present/past prenominal forms of "真面目", and I don't think these collide in any way with the です/でした copula at the end of the sentence.

1.これは真面目だった人です。
This *is* a person who *used to be*  serious.

2.これは真面目な人でした。
This *was* a serious person.

3.これは真面目だった人でした。
This *was* a person who *used to be* serious (but that changed at some point).

Answer (score -3):

1.これは真面目だった人です。 
2.これは真面目な人でした。 
3.これは真面目だった人でした。

Only sentence 2 is correct.
Both sentences 1 and 3 have the same verb (the copula だ) twice, which is weird and unnecessary.